# CSS background-image reference in javascript using codigniter

Tags: jquery, css, path

I am working in codeigniter my folder structure something like that.

```
application
assets
    css
    js
    img
system
index.php
```

I've to make my bootstrap carousel full window height.
my approach is that make my div.item layer to full height of window using jquery.
then remove image from div.item layer and set this image as div.item background image using jquery.

here is my jquery code.

```
$('.carousel').find('.item img').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        src = $(this).attr('src');
        imageName = 'url(assets/img/' + $(this).attr('src').split('/')[6]+')';
    $this.parent().css('background-image',imageName);
    $this.remove();
});
```

my reference in not working please let me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: It might be to do with how CodeIgniter is locating the `img` folder in your structure.  There should be a `application/config/config.php` file where you can look at the Base Site URL.  Also, look at [https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Have you also tried debugging the JQuery code in Google Chrome?

Comment: @SteveCrocHunter yes i have debugged in chrome `imageName` variable it's return `url(assets/img/carousel-third.jpg)` but in inline css it's return full url `url(http://localhost/MyOwnSinglePageLayout/assets/img/carousel-first.jpg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your should use full reference. Try this.

```
$('.carousel').find('.item img').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    src = $this.attr('src');
    $this.parent().css('background-image',src);
    $this.remove();
});
```